# Wordpress - Cloak domain crash page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, .htaccess, dns

I've just bought a second level domain on altervista.org, the problem is that when I see my site on computer (using .altervista.org or .com) it's ok, even with inspector web and reactive design on safari.
But, when I see the website on my iPhone (safari or chrome) using mydomain.com or www.mydomain.com it crashes (black page), instead, if I see www.mydomain.altervista.org or mydomain.altervista.org I see it correctly.

I've activated cloak domain on my alter vista panel, where is the problem? 
Thanks in advice.

Comment: also a href="tel:xxx" doesn't work in www.mydomain.com , it works on www.mydomain.altervista.org

Comment: you must provide your code or your website link

Comment: www.ironboundtattoo.com

Comment: I think the problem is related to frame , why you are using frames?

Comment: frames are not supported in html5 , you must do some settings in your domain instead of doing frames

Comment: please explain better, what settings?

Comment: I mean dns , but try that http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/htaccess/redirect-without-changing-url